# How to Generate Report on Frequently Opened Wiki Pages

Tags: auditing, enterprise-wiki, analytics

I would like to tally the number of visits to each of the individual wiki pages in a enterprise-wiki page library.  I am runnning on sharepoint 2016.

If the audit reporting can capture this information, I haven't been able to find out how.  Is there a certain type of report that I need to "run?" If so, is it a content activity report?

If I need to make changes to my "audit log trimming" configuration, or anything else in the "Configure Audit Settings" in the  Site Collection Administration section of the Top Level Site Settings, what exactly needs to be changed?
Have not been able to find a specific solution.

From searching online, I read that logging webpage visits is possible, but each article/tutorial doesn't actually go beyond an explanation of the audit log reporting or trimming.

---

ALSO, ideally, I would like to be able to create a view of the most popular wiki pages on my subsite's home page.  This would be a dynamic view where the most frequently visited pages will be displayed.  Is there an OOTB solution for this that can be automated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix. Linked articles provided good overview of writing queries that helped me to create a dynamic list of wiki pages based on total number of LifeTime page views (using CSWP). Article 1: [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/27069.sharepoint-2013-showing-page-views-within-a-sharepoint-page.aspx) Article 2: [link](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Step-by-steps-on-how-to-display-Most-Visited-Sites-with-number-of-view-count-in-SharePoint-2013-Web-Analytics) Auditing reporting wasn't even necessary. I "sorted" results by *ViewsLifeTime*